# How does the reshape function reshape 2 flatten 1d array stacked together horizontally?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reshape

I have two images with dimension of 100x100. Whenever I flatten them to 1-D arrays stack them afterwards I dont't get the same output as compared to when I stack them, the flatten them. What is the difference between these two approaches:

```
First_image  = I1
Second_image = I2
I = np.hstack((I1.flatten(), I2.flatten()))
plt.imshow((I).reshape((100,2*100)));
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TSfg.png)

```
First_image  = I1
Second_image = I2
I = np.hstack((I1, I2)).flatten()
plt.imshow((I).reshape((100,2*100)));
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugrmy.png)

Comment: Why should it be the same?

Answer (score 1):

You can clearly see the difference of the two by a simple code snippet attached

```
 import numpy as np
 a = np.ones((2,5))
 b = np.zeros((2,5))
 I = np.hstack((a.flatten(), b.flatten()))
 print(I)
 I = np.hstack((a, b)).flatten()
 print(I)
```

In general please do sanity checks with simple arrays yourself before posting questions here.

Comment: Yes the difference is very clear. Rather I was trying to understand why stacking 2 flattened arrays returns a duplicated image when you reshape it?